# Tutorial or similar for PoseBone

Tags: python, animation, pose-mode

I am new to blender and bpy. The goal of my project is to perform movements with a human model (from MakeHuman) but this movement should be possible to be applyied to all characters which are following. Therefore I use bpy and especially the poseBone struct but with the documentation (link is provided in [1]) alone I do not come along. That is why I am asking for some tutorials, books, or anything where things are explained more in detailed and where is shown on how to use them properly.

[1] https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_58_release/bpy.types.PoseBone.html#bpy.types.PoseBone.location

Comment: Welcome to BSE Markus, it'll help if you describe a specific thing you want to do with bpy,, that way people can focus on one thing. Often knowing how to do one small thing will show you how to do many related things. BSE isn't really an exchange site for links to tutorials. Altho we have gathered some here : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: the link already helped a lot. I just needed some comprehensive collection. Sorry if topic was not appropriate for the forum purpose. Thanks for your help anyway